# How to load properties from parent module root in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, classpath

I have a multi module application and in the parent I have a properties file that the user will be able to modify. In one of the sub modules I have a spring project that tries to load the properties and inject it.

If i move the properties file to the resources directory of the spring project I can load and inject it no issues such as

```
<util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:service.properties" />
```

However the user is unable to modify these from here annoyingly.

Is there another way to load the properties file from the parents root directory?

Thanks

Comment: You can load properties from filesystem using `file:` prefix, for example `location="file:/service.properties"` ?

Comment: if you answer this i can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven you can do that by using

`<resource>
        <directory>your Resource</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
</resource>`